# REGEX - Matching any character which repeats n times

Tags: regex, repeat, regex-lookarounds

How to match any character which repeats `n` times?

Example:

```
for input: abcdbcdcdd
for n=1:   ..........
for n=2:    .........
for n=3:     .. .....
for n=4:      .  . ..
for n=5:   no matches
```

After several hours my best is this expression

```
(\w)(?=(?:.*\1){n-1,}) //where n is variable
```

which uses lookahead. However the problem with this expression is this:

```
for input: abcdbcdcdd
for n=1    .......... 
for n=2     ... .. .
for n=3      ..  .
for n=4       .
for n=5    no matches
```

As you can see, when lookahead matches for a character, let's look *`for n=4`* line, `d`'s lookahead assertion satisfied and first `d` matched by regex. But remaining `d`'s are not matched because they don't have 3 more `d`'s ahead of them.

I hope I stated the problem clearly. Hoping for your solutions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> let's look for n=4 line, d's lookahead assertion satisfied
>   and first d matched by regex.
>   But remaining d's are not matched because they don't have 3 more d's
>   ahead of them.
>
> > And obviously, without regex, this is a very simple string manipulation
> >     problem. I'm trying to do this with and only with regex.

As with any regex implementation, the answer depends on the regex flavour. You could create a solution with [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) regex engine, because it allows variable width lookbehinds.

Also, I'll provide a more generalized solution below for perl-compatible/like regex flavours.

---

### .net Solution

As [@PetSerAl pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33184644/5290909), with variable width lookbehinds, we can assert back to the beggining of the string, and check there are **n** occurrences.
<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/1cXfty)</kbd>

**regex module in Python**
You can implement this solution in [python](/questions/tagged/python), using the [`regex module` by Matthew Barnett](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), which also allows variable-width lookbehinds.

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall( r'(\w)(?<=(?=(?>.*?\1){2})\A.*)', 'abcdbcdcdd')
['b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd']
>>> regex.findall( r'(\w)(?<=(?=(?>.*?\1){3})\A.*)', 'abcdbcdcdd')
['c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd']
>>> regex.findall( r'(\w)(?<=(?=(?>.*?\1){4})\A.*)', 'abcdbcdcdd')
['d', 'd', 'd', 'd']
>>> regex.findall( r'(\w)(?<=(?=(?>.*?\1){5})\A.*)', 'abcdbcdcdd')
[]
```

---

---

### Generalized Solution

In [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) or any of the "perl-like" flavours, there is no solution that would actually return a *match* for every repeated character, but we could create one, and only one, *capture* for each character.

#### Strategy

For any given **n**, the logic involves:

1. **Early matches:** Match and capture every character followed by *at least* **n** more occurences.
2. **Final captures:**

   - Match and capture a character followed by *exactly* **n-1** occurences, and
   - also capture every one of the following occurrences.

#### Example

```
for n = 3
input = abcdbcdcdd
```

The character `c` is **M**atched only once (as final), and the following 2 occurrences are also **C**aptured in the same match:

```
abcdbcdcdd
  M  C C
```

and the character `d` is (early) **M**atched once:

```
abcdbcdcdd
   M
```

and (finally) **M**atched one more time, **C**apturing the rest:

```
abcdbcdcdd
      M CC
```

---

#### Regex

```
/(\w)                        # match 1 character
(?:
    (?=(?:.*?\1){≪N≫})     # [1] followed by other ≪N≫ occurrences
  |                          #   OR
    (?=                      # [2] followed by:
        (?:(?!\1).)*(\1)     #      2nd occurence <captured>
        (?:(?!\1).)*(\1)     #      3rd occurence <captured>
        ≪repeat previous≫  #      repeat subpattern (n-1) times
                             #     *exactly (n-1) times*
        (?!.*?\1)            #     not followed by another occurence
    )
)/xg
```

For **`n =`**

2. `/(\w)(?:(?=(?:.*?\1){2})|(?=(?:(?!\1).)*(\1)(?!.*?\1)))/g`
   <kbd>[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aU1sT6/1)</kbd>
3. `/(\w)(?:(?=(?:.*?\1){3})|(?=(?:(?!\1).)*(\1)(?:(?!\1).)*(\1)(?!.*?\1)))/g`
   <kbd>[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aU1sT6/2)</kbd>
4. `/(\w)(?:(?=(?:.*?\1){4})|(?=(?:(?!\1).)*(\1)(?:(?!\1).)*(\1)(?:(?!\1).)*(\1)(?!.*?\1)))/g`
   <kbd>[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aU1sT6/3)</kbd>
5. ... etc.

#### Pseudocode to generate the pattern

```
// Variables: N (int)

character = "(\w)"
early_match = "(?=(?:.*?\1){" + N + "})"

final_match = "(?="
for i = 1; i < N; i++
    final_match += "(?:(?!\1).)*(\1)"
final_match += "(?!.*?\1))"

pattern = character + "(?:" + early_match + "|" + final_match + ")"
```

---

#### JavaScript Code

I'll show an implementation using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) because we can check the result here (and if it works in javascript, it works in any perl-compatible regex flavour, including [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), [java](/questions/tagged/java), [python](/questions/tagged/python), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), and all languages that implemented [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre), among others).

```js
var str = 'abcdbcdcdd';
var pattern, re, match, N, i;
var output = "";

// We'll show the results for N = 2, 3 and 4
for (N = 2; N <= 4; N++) {
    // Generate pattern
    pattern = "(\\w)(?:(?=(?:.*?\\1){" + N + "})|(?=";
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        pattern += "(?:(?!\\1).)*(\\1)";
    }
    pattern += "(?!.*?\\1)))";
    re = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
    
    output += "<h3>N = " + N + "</h3><pre>Pattern: " + pattern + "\nText: " + str;
    
    // Loop all matches
    while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
        output += "\nPos: " + match.index + "\tMatch:";
        // Loop all captures
        x = 1;
        while (match[x] != null) {
            output += " " + match[x];
            x++;
        }
    }
    
    output += "</pre>";
}

document.write(output);
```

#### Python3 code

As requested by the OP, I'm linking to a <kbd>[Python3 implementation in ideone.com](http://ideone.com/JzQcMy)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your very informative answer! So the solution seems using a strong regex flavor where you can use lookaheads and lookbehind one in another. I wonder if it's possible in Python3. Because I tried it in Python3 all night :)

Comment: Certainly, you can implement it in Python. I added the code [here](http://ideone.com/JzQcMy). And to clarify, the c# solution uses a lookahead nested in a lookbehind. The generalized solution only uses lookaheads, and they're OR'ed, not nested.

Answer (score 7):

Regular expressions (and finite automata) are not able to count to arbitrary integers. They can only count to a predefined integer and fortunately this is your case.

Solving this problem is much easier if we first construct a nondeterministic finite automata (NFA) ad then convert it to regular expression.

So the following automata for n=2 and input alphabet = {a,b,c,d}
[image]

will match any string that has exactly 2 repetitions of any char. If no character has 2 repetitions (all chars appear less or more that two times) the string will not match.

Converting it to regex should look like

```
"^([^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*)|([^b]*b[^b]*b[^b]*)|([^b]*c[^c]*c[^C]*)|([^d]*d[^d]*d[^d]*)$"
```

This can get problematic if the input alphabet is big, so that regex should be shortened somehow, but I can't think of it right now.

Comment: Thank you for informative answer! Building NFA is good way of thinking regex problems, it reminded me the Formal Languages and Automata course I took at the college. However, as you said, this regex is infeasible as its extremely long, we should find a shorter solution. Therefore I'm upvoting your answer but not marking as accepted.

Comment: Tank you for this answer. I needed an Automata solution not that of a  programming language.

Answer (score 4):

With .NET regular expressions you can do following:

```
(\w)(?<=(?=(?:.*\1){n})^.*) where n is variable
```

Where:

- `(\w)` — any character, captured in first group.
- `(?<=^.*)` — lookbehind assertion, which return us to the start of the string.
- `(?=(?:.*\1){n})` — lookahead assertion, to see if string have `n` instances of that character.

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cw%29%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3d%28%3f%3a.*%5c1%29%7b4%7d%29%5e.*%29&i=abcdbcdcdd)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have upvoted but, Mariano's answer is far better, so I'm marking his answer as accepted.

It seems the solution of this problem is  using a very strong regex flavor, where you can use lookbehinds and lookaheads one in another. 

I wonder, if it's possible in Python3.

Comment: @Saibot This is indeed an outstanding solution, and not necessarily intuitive. All "perl-like" flavors allow nested lookarounds, the issue is about supporting variable-width lookbehinds like `(?<=^re.*)`. You can implement this in Python with an external module. The [`regex module` by Matthew Barnett](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) also allows variable-width lookbehinds.

Answer (score 3):

I would not use regular expressions for this. I would use a scripting language such as python. Try out this python function:

```
alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
def get_matched_chars(n, s):
    s = s.lower()
    return [char for char in alpha if s.count(char) == n]
```

The function will return a list of characters, all of which appear in the string s exactly n times. Keep in mind that I only included letters in my alphabet. You can change alpha to represent anything that you want to get matched.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but we all know how to do without regex. And obviously, without regex, this is a very simple string manipulation problem. I'm trying to do this with and only with regex.