# vim: my regexp to select some words doesnt work

Tags: regex, vim

Sentences = lines that may contain anything (including html tags). I have a lot of sentences like that. Those sentences are in a *huge* text where I dont want to remove *all tags* (I want all other lines to remain untouched):

```
<h2 id="aa"><a href="/bb/cc/dd">sentence</a></h2>
<h2 id="xx"><a href="/yy/tt">Another sentence</a></h2>
```

And sometimes only:

```
<h2 id="aa">A sentence without a link</h2>
```

First thing that I find strange: I'm trying to search for any caracter and fill a group. I've tried all those solutions:

- `\(.\)\+` -> select whole line
- `\([.]\)\+` -> select only the "`.`" caracter
- `\([\.]\)\+` -> select only the "`.`" caracter
- `\([\.]\)\+` -> *still* select only the "`.`" caracter (what the?)

From the documentation, if I want to select a group of any caracters and fill a register I thought I could use that expression but it doesnt work: `\([\.]\+\)`. The only "close" expression that works is `\(.\)\+` but if I try to output the register it's only filled with *the last* caracter matched.

So starting from this problem above, I can't do what I want which is convert all the sentences above by this output:

```
---sentence
---Another sentence
---A sentence without a link
```

I've tried something like `:%s/^<h2 id=\(\[.\]\+\)<a\([.]\)\+>\(.\)\+<\/a><\/h2>$/--->\3/` but it didnt work properly, and didnt include sentences that did not have *`<a />`* tag inside

How would you do this?

Comment: I read your edit again and can I assume you just need to remove the html tags in and include the <h> tag?

Comment: @Olivier Pons, I really don't get why my regex doesn't fit your problem. Can you please define an input and output set? For example: "for input x y z, I want the regex gives the output a b c"

Comment: @Olivier Pons, Please take a look my regex question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181434/regex-matching-any-character-which-repeats-n-times , for proper input and output set giving.

Comment: `%s/<h[^>]*>\(<[^>]*>\)*\([^<]*\).*/--- \2/g`  does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the regex below:

```
>([^<>]+)<
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mS2oB5/2

For full text:

```
>([^<>\n]+)<
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mS2oB5/3

Comment: I didnt explain myself properly: those sentences are in a full text where I dont want to remove *all tags*

Comment: @Olivier Pons I edited my answer to cover full texts, just by adding '\n'. If what you want is something else, please provide desired outputs for given inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Vim in command mode , type
`%s/<[^>]*>//g`.

Explaination:
1.`\([\.]\)\+` still select only the "." caracter.Because the character in the `[]` is treated as normal chars, they dont have regex special meaning.

2.My Regex `<[^>]*>` is a simple way to remove all html tags.Will have some problems, but I will leave it to you.

3.`<[^>]*>` have another version `<.*?>` with include the `greedy` featrue of regex.

Comment: Your answer is good, but is this tricky? `<.\{-}>` why? and if you can do `<[^>]*>`, `.*?` is not a better version. It will be slower than the first one. and the `.*?` can only work with PCRE, the first works for BRE ERE PCRE

Comment: I didnt explain myself properly: those sentences are in a full text where I dont want to remove *all tags*

Comment: @Kent Thank you for your advise.I will modify my answer.

Comment: @OlivierPons Then what's the defination of sentences?Text between **any** tag or just <h> <a>?

Comment: I update my question again, thank you for asking precision